# HTTP Post undefined in node

Tags: node.js, post, slack

I'm trying to create an app in Node.JS that receives POST requests. At the moment, I have them tunneled through ngrok, and I can get the headers without a problem, but I can't get the request body. Here's my code:

```
const http = require("http");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const qs = require("qs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const slackSigningSecret = process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET;
    
http.createServer(function(request) {
  let x_slack_signature = request.headers["x-slack-signature"]; // Get the Slack signature
  let raw_body = request.body; // Get the request body
  let x_slack_timestamp = request.headers["x-slack-request-timestamp"]; // Get the timestamp of the request

(...)

}).listen(3000);
```

But when I make a console log with the variables I defined, `raw_body` returns either empty or undefined.
I have tried to `qs.stringify` since I was reading that seemed to work. Also with body parser; I get this error `body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option`. If I write the extended option then it outputs this:

```
function urlencodedParser (req, res, next) {
    if (req._body) {
      debug('body already parsed')
      next()
      return
    }

    req.body = req.body || {}

    // skip requests without bodies
    if (!typeis.hasBody(req)) {
      debug('skip empty body')
      next()
      return
    }

    debug('content-type %j', req.headers['content-type'])

    // determine if request should be parsed
    if (!shouldParse(req)) {
      debug('skip parsing')
      next()
      return
    }

    // assert charset
    var charset = getCharset(req) || 'utf-8'
    if (charset !== 'utf-8') {
      debug('invalid charset')
      next(createError(415, 'unsupported charset "' + charset.toUpperCase() + '"', {
        charset: charset,
        type: 'charset.unsupported'
      }))
      return
    }

    // read
    read(req, res, next, parse, debug, {
      debug: debug,
      encoding: charset,
      inflate: inflate,
      limit: limit,
      verify: verify
    })
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am trying to get the full body first, then to divide it into something like an array of some sorts 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using the `express` framework to help you build a robust web server? It handles lots of details for you under the covers.

Comment: @O.Jones I have tried using express as you advised me and it also gives me an error. When I try to print the variable in which I assigned the output, this comes out:
```
function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  }
```